# findWithinHorizon keeps reading while it should fail

Tags: java, parsing

I've the following code to interactively parse System.in for arrow keypresses:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String str;
if ((str = sc.findWithinHorizon("\\G\\033\\[C", 0)) != null)
  System.out.println("RIGHT ARROW");
else if ((str = sc.findWithinHorizon("\\G\\033\\[D", 0)) != null)
  System.out.println("LEFT ARROW");
```

when I press first the right arrow all goes well, but when I press first the left one, findWithinHorizon hangs waiting for more input while it should fail and return null.

With this behaviour, I don't see how to use this technique to program a general pattern-matching parser.

Any clues?

thanks, Francesc

Comment: I would consider a different approach, perhaps something designed to work with a key at a time (and take care of buffering, or the lack-of, or whatnot) -- that is *accept the data* and *then* act on it. This is quite similar to an an A B / B A lock deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

`findWithinHorizon` waits until it finds something. You could try the pattern

```
\\G\\033\\[C|\\G\\033\\[D
```

and then look at the strings content.

Comment: Problem is it doesn't scale. Perhaps a better solution is:

\\G\\033\\\[C|\\G

instead of

\\G\033\\\[C

making pattern always match and then compare lengths.

Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is it doesn't scale. Perhaps a better solution is:

```
\\G\\033\\[C|\\G
```

instead of

```
\\G\033\\[C
```

making pattern always match and then compare lengths.

Any other alternatives?